# Chrome closes itself just after it loads for mobile web automation

Tags: continuous-integration, appium

Chrome browser opens and automatically closes while mobile web automation.
The code doesn't proceeds any further. I'm using real device and appium version 1.6 and chrome version 54.

Desired Capabilities :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Testing device");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 7200);
```

Driver Initialisation :

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> aDriver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), setCapabilities());
System.out.println(aDriver.getSessionId());
aDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
aDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Appium log :

```
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
[AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
[AndroidDriver] Starting a chrome-based browser session
[debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'starting'
[Chromedriver] Set chromedriver binary as: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver
[Chromedriver] Killing any old chromedrivers, running: pkill -15 -f "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver.*--port=9515"
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
[Chromedriver] No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
[Chromedriver] Spawning chromedriver with: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver --url-base=wd/hub --port=9515 --adb-port=5037
[Chromedriver] [STDOUT] Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/status] with no body
[Chromedriver] [STDERR] [warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"\",\"stat...
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"ch...
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"e1cc8c5acefcf...
[debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'online'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session 4cd47498-3a35-495e-8cdd-1fd02e69427c added to master session list
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webSto...
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 21605 ms - 875
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/4cd47498-3a35-495e-8cdd-1fd02e69427c/timeouts {"type":"implicit","ms":10000}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/4cd47498-3a35-495e-8cdd-1fd02e69427c/timeouts] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/e1cc8c5acefcf0ef250abfcf6b59b61d/timeouts] with body: {"type":"implicit","ms":10000}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"e1cc8c5acefcf...
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId e1cc8c5acefcf0ef250abfcf6b59b61d with 4cd47498-3a35-495e-8cdd-1fd02e69427c
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/4cd47498-3a35-495e-8cdd-1fd02e69427c/timeouts 200 12 ms - 220
```

Could it be the some version problem of chrome installed or chrome-driver?

Comment: Please add driver initialisation and test code.